# Update and insert new value for existing value of multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with below columns (key, country, value) and one of the row names is `charge code`. Sample as below:

```
KEY         COUNTRY  VALUE
chargecode  US       ABC|DEF
```

I want to add new charge code `GHI` for all countries in this table, field separator was pipe. How should I do it?

Using insert will cause SQL Error `ORA-00001: unique constraint violated`

I can use update statement but update statement will use SET VALUE which I need to specify. The problem is each country has different charge code.

Comment: In which columns you want to add another charger code GHI.

Comment: You need to append a different value to your pipe-delimited column for each country, or they all get `GHI`? If they're different, where do they come from? (Why are you storing delimited data at all, rather than having the values as separate rows?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET    value = value||'|GHI';
```

Comment: I used like this: UPDATE central SET VALUE = VALUE||'|GHI'
where key = 'chargecode';